# Continuity of limit on a compact set implies uniform convergence

Tags: continuity, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence of increasing functions defined on $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Say that $f_n \to f$ pointwise, such that $f$ is continuous.

Does this imply that the convergence is also uniform?

Comment: How do you define the convergence $f_n\to f$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy pointwise convergence. edited.